# Enable multiple users to use audio input/output in parallel

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

I am running two users simultaneously on my Mac and I create a local VNC session to access one from the other. My issue is that when I try to play or record any sound on the other session (the one I'm accessing through VNC) no sound ever comes out of the speakers, same for recording audio. I suppose the main user might somehow "capture" the audio device and make it unavailable for other users.

Would there be a way to enable multiple users to input/output audio simultaneously, or at least select a "background" user to be able to input/output audio?